# Unique session value in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm developing a game and for starting the game the player need to specify a nickname.

The nickname is saved in $_SESSION['nickname'] and is taken from a get variable $_GET['nickname']

I dont' want that two players can play with the same Nickname.

How can I check for an already existing value in  $ _SESSION['nickname']?

Do I have to use sql database or just sessions?

I need something like this:

```
if($_GET['nickname'] in <SOMETHING>){
    echo 'This nickname is already in use';
}else{
    ...

    $_SESSION["nickname"] = $_GET['nickname'];
    echo 'The nickname has been registered';
}
```

Comment: You would need to use a database for this.

Comment: Adding to yivi's comment. Sessions are unique to a user. You need a shared storage, for this you can use a database table for users.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP Requests` are `Stateless`, You can't share `sessions` between two clients.

Here you need `Database` to `store` and `retrieve` data.

If you want to share **temporary session** you need to use `Redis` / `Memcache` as **session storage**

[Redis as Session Handler in PHP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-16-04)